# Ubuntu Server Ver. 16.04 Intel Centrino 6205 wireless card doesn't connect.

Tags: networking, wireless, server, intel-wireless

Ubuntu Server Ver. 16.04 using an intel Centrino 6205 wireless card. The card connected without fault during installation and worked perfectly. But I can't get it to connect after booting server, I am unable to get it to work. I have put all of the commands into /etc/network/interfaces, but the card will not connect. Does anyone know the correct parameters and precise procedure to set up the card? BTW - I have tried all of the copious suggestions elsewhere in the community threads...HELP...help...Thanks...

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `cat  /etc/network/interfaces` If there are any personally identifiable details, please obscure them, something like: <my_password>.  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved my problem. Here is what is needed:

1. install aptitude
   sudo apt-get install aptitude
2. install wpa_supplement   ***** note the "_" is not required in statement below
   sudo aptitude install wpasupplement
3. Read and understand and use parameters and follow instructions as follows:
   https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#wpa_supplicant
4. Modify /etc/network/interfaces:
   Comment out your hardwired Ethernet device
5. Modify /etc/network/interfaces by adding
   auto " characters
   iface < your wireless device as above> inet static|dhcp
   wpa_ssid 
   wpa_psk  < your access point password>
   ***** other parameters as needed, i.e address, netmask, network, gateway, etc.
   See examples in "HowToUse#wpa_supplement"
6. Reboot system to test that network is up and will stay up
7. worked great for me...good luck to you